# add_rewrite_rule with trailing slash redirects

Tags: rewrite-rules

I have made my own routes by using `add_rewrite_rule` method. I would like to know if it is possible using given method to force all my created routes to redirect to URL where there is trailing slash in the end. For example if i do

`add_rewrite_rule('^my-route/', 'index.php?_my_route=1', 'top')`

or

`add_rewrite_rule('^my-route', 'index.php?_my_route=1', 'top')`

and i make a call to `http://site.dev/my-route` then it does not redirect it to `http://site.dev/my-route/`. If it is possible then i would be thankful for sharing :).

Answer (score 0):

just change your rule to this

```
add_rewrite_rule('^my-route?$', 'index.php?_my_route=1', 'top')
```

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?

Comment: Did you mean `^my-route/?$`

Answer (score -1):

If think this will work for you
Add this is functions.php

```
add_action( 'init',function(){
  global $wp;
  $current_url = home_url(add_query_arg(array(),$wp->request));
  $last_char = substr($current_url, -1); 

 if($last_char == '/' && filter_var($current_url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)){
   wp_redirect( trailingslashit( $current_url ) );
 }
});
```

Comment: We can use others, if using only that method is not enough for redirection. Maybe other way is the only correct way, so ideas are welcomed! :)

Comment: @MarttinNotta Just to confirm you want to redirect the current url to url with slash at end if there is no slash? right?

Comment: Yes, this is what i want, but i would like it the way wordpress does it with its pages, if you have page names cartoons and you hit the page without no trailing slash then wordpress will make the redirect (no .htacces because im using nginx)

Comment: @MarttinNotta I updated answer check if it works and if you are not happy than you can comment

Comment: This redirect works indeed, but unfortunately i have to manually check it which is not what i entirely want... i managed to get my code working using only `add_rewrite_rule` but i have not fully understood why it does so. By the way i did not give you -1...